# mongodb check time passed since last update of collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, next.js

I have a Next.js project where I'm saving some stuff on MongoDB via Mongoose, based on logged user id and the collection looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId(" <a objectid> ")
id: " <a userid> "
__v: 0
subscribedTo: Object
```

My schema in this case is called `Sub` and I already use it successfully for a save/update operation in the same api route. I'd need to retrieve the `getTimestamp()` of the _id shown above I think but when i try to do so i get a messagge that "_id" is undefined:

```
    var doc = Sub.findOne({ 'id': userId });
    if (doc){
      console.log("ALL GOOD"); // this gets logged

      var timestamp = doc._id.getTimestamp(); // this says "_id" is undefined
      console.log("TIMESTAMP OK");
```

What I'm trying to do basically is to compare current Date with last creation/update of the entry, to see if a certain amount of time passed.